# Is it bad practice not to use foreign key

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have a parent and child table in a one to many relationship. What I have done is that I created a search method where user would find the ID from a parent table, result showing on A label97. They would then insert a child record and use the result shown in the label to link the two tables up. So I have not done a foreign key using @@identity. So my question is the method I have done is it bad practice? Because the result looks good in the database. This is my code. Thanks.

Main.cs

```
    private void btnSearch2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         myCon.Open();
          cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM EmployMainDetails WHERE EID = @EID", myCon);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EID", textBox2.Text);
          try
          {
              dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
              if (dreader.Read())
              {

                 label97.Text = dreader["EID"].ToString();
              }
                 else MessageBox.Show("No record found");
          }

          catch (Exception)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(" No Record");
          }
          finally
          {
              myCon.Close();
          }
     }

    private void btnJNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EEmployDetails.JInsert(txtJobID.Text, label97.Text, cBEmpStatus.Text, ...); 
    }
```

EmployDetails.cs

This is my insert method

```
 public static void JInsert(string ejobid, string eid, string employst,... )
    {
        var con = GetConnection();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = (@"INSERT INTO EmploymentDetails (EJobID, EID, EmploymentStatus,...)
         VALUES(@EJobID, @EID, @EmploymentStatus, ...)");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EJobID", ejobid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID", eid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmploymentStatus", employst);
        ....
        ...
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You should always use a foreign key to enforce referential integrity.

Comment: @DarrenDavies - Actually I did not made it clear that I did referential integrity in Access. What I meant was do I need to do something at the front end. But did doesn't matter now, thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminology seems to be muddled. You say that you "have not done a foreign key using @@identity", but you *are* using a foreign key, otherwise there would be no link between the parent and child tables.

In your case, `EID` appears to be the *foreign key* in the child table(s), matching a corresponding *primary key* in the parent table. Each child table may also have its own *primary key* defined, and that primary key may be an *identity column* (what Access calls an "AutoNumber" field), but that is a different matter.

So you are already using a foreign key. Darren's comment above refers to "referential integrity", which is a mechanism to ensure that child records always have a corresponding parent record. This is often called a "foreign key constraint", and in Access it can be achieved by creating a "Relationship" between two tables and then choosing the "Enforce Referential Integrity" option

[image: relationship.png]

Comment: Yes I have done this, also for Cascade Update Related Fields and Delete Related Records. I meant perhaps I had to use @@identity in my search method. I wasn't sure if I was doing this correctly but from what you have written I was on right track. thanks